# Setup different launch screen interface on ipad/iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I am trying to setup different launch-screen `.xib` file in my iPhone application.

I want to know is there any way I can setup different launch screen file in iPad version and iPhone version. Just like Xcode allows different storyboard for iPad/iPhone. I think there must be an option.

**Have a look at below screen shot.**
[image: launch file name]

Comment: is it just an image? or you have special xib file?

Comment: i want to add special xib file for ipad version..

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to do this at present, there is only one slot in the info.plist and there is no way you have any code running at this stage (hence the need for a launch image in the first place)  Until Apple provide a key to specify an iPad launch xib as they have with Main nib, main storyboard etc..  probably not likely to ever happen, as the move to a launch xib seems designed to reduce the number of device/size specific assets required

Comment: @shujatAli : What u have in xib file?

Answer (score 16):

I created two storyboard files for example:
LaunchScreen_iPhone.storyboard and
LaunchScreen_iPad.storyboard.
Doesn't have to be those exact names. The file names are referenced from the Info.plist file.

In the Info.plist file edit the "Launch screen interface file base name" (UILaunchStoryboardName) key value to "LaunchScreen_iPhone"

Create another key-value entry in the Info.plist in the key name "UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad" and value "LaunchScreen_iPad"

Answer (score 11):

In the Info.plist file, create another entry called `UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad` and set it to your `LaunchScreeniPad.xib`

Comment: There is nothing called "UILaunchStoryboardName~ipad" in info.plist.

Answer (score 6):

Create two .xib files named

LaunchScreen2~iphone.xib

LaunchScreen2~ipad.xib

Comment: This worked, it is case sensitive though ~iPhone and ~iPad will not work

Comment: This condition not working for me. Please can you help me to find solution? "Launch screen interface file base name : LaunchScreen2"- This is giving blank screen. I have to mention here LaunchScreen2~ipad or LaunchScreen2~iphone anyone.

Comment: I agree. It only gives a white image when building from Xcode 7.2.

Comment: @joelg Did you add Info,plist entry as shown in the other answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use storyboard based Launchscreen and make device dependent layout in one file.

Layout your launchscreen for iphone with size classes `(w: Any, h: Any)`, then change size classes to `w: Regular, h: Regular` and layout it again for iPad by uninstalling conflicting views/constraints and installing new.

You can read more about adaptive layout here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started

I believe this is recommended approach since Apple introduced features like Split View. That way you can launch your app on iPad but with screen size of iPhone.