# Different launch screen in iOS

Tags: swift, swift2

Through the `applicationDelegate` I have different storyboards for different resolutions. Can I do the same thing for the launch screen?

Comment: Are you creating completely different layouts (like different elements) for different resolutions? Or is it more an adaption to the resolutions? This is what Apple calls "Adaptive Apps", described here: https://developer.apple.com/design/adaptivity/

Comment: @jboi You can still add different elements for only some resolutions with adaptive layout.

Comment: I'm resizing all for different resolutions . I wanted to know if there a way to call different launchScreen for different resolutions @jboi

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible to have multiple files anymore as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27777901/setup-different-launch-screen-interface-on-ipad-iphone)

The recommended approach is to create a Universal Storyboard. You can see how to go about doing that [here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)

Answer (score -1):

This solution comes from the blog post [*How to load UIStoryboards depending on screen height in iOS*](http://pinkstone.co.uk/how-to-load-uistoryboards-depending-on-screen-height-in-ios/):

> ```
> - (UIStoryboard *)grabStoryboard {
>
>     // determine screen size
>     int screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
>     UIStoryboard *storyboard;
>
>     switch (screenHeight) {
>
>             // iPhone 4s
>         case 480:
>             storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-4s" bundle:nil];
>             break;
>
>             // iPhone 5s
>             case 568:
>             storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-5s" bundle:nil];
>             break;
>
>             // iPhone 6
>             case 667:
>             storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6" bundle:nil];
>             break;
>
>             // iPhone 6 Plus
>             case 736:
>             storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-6-Plus" bundle:nil];
>             break;
>
>         default:
>             // it's an iPad
>             storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
>             break;
>     }
>
>     return storyboard;
> }
> ```

Comment: If you want to modify your question, modify the _question_. Do not misuse the answer. You can answer if you have an _answer_ to your own question.

Comment: This is not Swift code. Either post an answer in Swift or change your question's tag to "objective-c" please.